# Is there a way to show that the mean of a group is at zero?

Tags: ggplot2, data-visualization, geom-bar

I am trying to make a quick graph to show the means of a few groups. My `y axis` ranges from `-2` to `+2`. Two of my groups have a mean of zero, therefore nothing shows up on the graph. Is there a good way to depict the two means at zero? Zero is a meaningful number. I was thinking like a small pink bar or blue bar.

Any suggestions? Sorry in advance for the messy code!

```r
conseq_summary_table=structure(list(age_group = c("4", "4", "5", "5", "adult", "adult"), 
condition_motive = c("bad", "good", "bad", "good", "bad", "good"), 
group_conseq_mean = c(0, 0.192307692307, 0.133333333333, 
   -0.0333333333333, -0.710526315789, 0), 
conseq_sd = c(0.577350269189, 0.722797272709, 
   0.549891764241,0.611399643285, 0.450795268685, 0)), 
row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
groups = structure(list(age_group = c("4", "5", "adult"), 
 .rows = list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Here is my current code:

```r
    ggplot(conseq_summary_table, aes(age_group, conseq_mean )) +
      geom_bar(aes(fill = condition_motive), stat = "identity", position = "dodge",
               alpha = .7) +
      labs(title = "Summary of conseq", x = "Age Group", y = "Average conseq" ) +
        theme_minimal() +
      scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),
                         limits = c(-2,2)) +
      geom_hline(yintercept=0)
```

[image: Bar plot]

Comment: welcome to SO. your code is not really messy, but unfortunately not reproducible. It helps us help you to have a good example. Check out [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Finally, you may want to [check out stat_summary](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/0.9.1/topics/stat_summary)

Comment: Please add the output off `dput(conseq_summary_table)`, this will help us help you :-)

Comment: structure(list(age_group = c("4", "4", "5", "5", "adult", "adult"), condition_motive = c("bad", "good", "bad", "good", "bad", "good"), group_conseq_mean = c(0, 0.192307692307, 0.133333333333, -0.0333333333333, -0.710526315789, 0), conseq_sd = c(0.577350269189, 0.722797272709, 0.549891764241,0.611399643285, 0.450795268685, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(age_group = c("4", "5", "adult"), .rows = list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE)) Thanks @TobiO

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! @Tjebo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's not really my remit, but may I allow myself some comments on your plot?

- **For what you want to show, bar plots are not appropriate**. I think one of the reasons you were struggling with this visualisation is just because of that. If you want to show mean and standard deviation, a much more appropriate visualisation are dots with error bars.
- **Whenever possible, calculate summary statistics within ggplot2**! There is often no need of pre-processing your data. Now there are obviously several reasons why you may not have this data. Sometimes one can't get around pre-processing. But if you should have access to the raw data, your case would be a perfect example for the use of summary stats such as above mentioned or box plots.
- **Think about using facets!** Separating your data visually helps the reader a lot to identify patterns and to "see the story". Your task would be to find the best facet for visualisation!
- **Don't use axis limits that do not make sense!** In your case, stick to 1 rather than 2. As a matter of fact, ggplot often choses very reasonable limits - so you may not need to specify limits at all! And if you limit your axes, best to do this within `coord_...()` calls
- **The default colors are ggplot2's one big flaw** However, there is an integrated set of color palettes based on https://colorbrewer2.org- you can chose color blind friendly palettes etc.

Below a suggestion how I would plot this based on the above comments:

```r
library(ggplot2)

conseq_summary_table <- structure(list(age_group = c("4", "4", "5", "5", "adult", "adult"), condition_motive = c("bad", "good", "bad", "good", "bad", "good"), group_conseq_mean = c(0, 0.192307692307, 0.133333333333, -0.0333333333333, -0.710526315789, 0), conseq_sd = c(0.577350269189, 0.722797272709, 0.549891764241,0.611399643285, 0.450795268685, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(age_group = c("4", "5", "adult"), .rows = list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))

ggplot(conseq_summary_table, aes(age_group, group_conseq_mean )) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin= group_conseq_mean - conseq_sd, 
                      ymax = group_conseq_mean + conseq_sd, color = condition_motive),
                  position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1') +
  scale_y_continuous() +
  facet_wrap(~ age_group, scales = 'free_x') # maybe try facetting by condition_motive instead
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much, @tjebo. Your suggestions are very helpful, and I agree that is a much better way to display my data and story.